# Interpretation of proportion coefficient in linear regression

Tags: regression, proportion

If I have an equation:

`income = 22 + 12 * (hrs_prop)`,

where `hrs_prop` is the proportion of hours spent assuming between 0 and 0.24 and `income` is in thousand of dollars.

How can I interpret the slope?

What does one unit change mean here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackExchange! Hope you learn a lot in this forum.

The generic expression for a linear equation with one independent variable is $y = \alpha + \beta x$.

The slope, $(\beta)$ expresses the rate of change or, in other words, the ratio of the vertical and horizontal changes between two points. That means, if you vary one unit of your independent variable ($x$), your dependent variable ($y$) will vary $\beta$ units. In your example, if you increase one unit of `hrs_prop`, the `income` will increase 12 thousand of dollars (although it does not make sense to increase a unit a proportion, serve as an example).

Comment: Thank you David for your reply. But since the independent variable is in proportion. How to interpret the increase of one unit?

Comment: @RogKa Divide by $100$ to get increments of one "proportion point". If you increase the proportion by $0.01$, then $y$ increases by $\hat\beta/100$. // Since it is silly to increase a proportion by $1$, it could be worth mentioning this in the answer. // If you want to talk about percent increases, where increasing from $0.1$ to $0.2$ is a $100\%$ increase instead of a $0.1$ increase, life gets harder. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding properly your question. Let's suppose the increase of the ```hrs_prop``` is $n, \ \forall \ n \ \in \ [0, 0.24]$. The result of increasing $n$ units ```hrs_prop``` will result in an increase of $\beta \cdot n$ the variable ```income``` . For example, if the proportion increases 0.1 units, the ```income``` will increase $0.1 \cdot 12$ units. In your particular case, that will result in an increase of 1.2 thousand of dollars.

Comment: The example clarifies. thanks a ton